# Issue with base_url in external JS files in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm migrating a Codeigniter web app from Google App Engine (GAE) to AWS.

In GAE I used to refer base_url in external javascript files as

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
```

But when I move the code to AWS this is not working and I'm forced to use static references like

```
    var url = 'http://app.example.com/index.php/';
```

This is cumbersome as we are forced to change this before each deployment.

Can someone please help us to address this issue?

P.S. index.php in the url is not a concern here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331749/jquery-in-codeigniter-inside-the-view-or-in-external-js-file

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the Codeigniter `base_url()` function. Make sure to define this in the `config.php` file and then you can use it in the JS files.

> Note that you can load different `config.php` file according to the
>   environment.

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://app.example.com/';`

Then in the javascript files, you can use this snippet to grab the URL.

`var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>'`

You can, in fact, create a javascript function `base_url()` in JS using the above `var` in JS files.